# Get product name from msi file in C#

Tags: c#, .net, windows-installer

I have an msi file that installs an application. I need to know the product name of that application *before* the installation starts.

I tried the following:

```
{ 

...
Type type = Type.GetType("Windows.Installer");
WindowsInstaller.Installer installer = (WindowsInstaller.Installer)
Activator.CreateInstance(type);

installer.OpenDatabase(msiFile, 0); //this is my guess to pass in the msi file name...
...
}
```

but now? Type is *null*, which throws me an error. And where do I pass in the name of the MSI file?

Thanks for any hints & comments.

Comment: any final full source code about it ?

Answer (score 6):

You need to use:

```
        Type installerType = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("WindowsInstaller.Installer");
```

Here is a sample from some of my code - in my case I get the installer version:

```
        // Get the type of the Windows Installer object
        Type installerType = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("WindowsInstaller.Installer");

        // Create the Windows Installer object
        Installer installer = (Installer)Activator.CreateInstance(installerType);

        // Open the MSI database in the input file
        Database database = installer.OpenDatabase(inputFile, MsiOpenDatabaseMode.msiOpenDatabaseModeReadOnly);

        // Open a view on the Property table for the version property
        View view = database.OpenView("SELECT * FROM Property WHERE Property = 'ProductVersion'");

        // Execute the view query
        view.Execute(null);

        // Get the record from the view
        Record record = view.Fetch();

        // Get the version from the data
        string version = record.get_StringData(2);
```

Comment: is there solution without use COM ?

Answer (score 2):

Wouldn't it be easier to use this code:

`Type type = typeof(Windows.Installer);`

If you prefer the Type.GetType(String) overload you must include correct assembly name after full path to class, eg.:

`Type type = Type.GetType("Windows.Installer, <assembly for MsiInstaller>");`

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have no preferences, I am just googling the web and hope to find some way to solve my problem. What do you mean with "assembly for MsiInstaller"? I just have the msi file. But the "typeof" method seems not to work, either (type Installer does not exist).

Comment: If the "Windows.Installer" is not in mscorlib or in currently executing assembly then you must specificy the name of assembly in Type.GetType(string).

There is a typo in typeof(). It should be typeof(WindowsInstaller) without the dot.

Answer (score 1):

Where did you get the "Windows.Installer" stuff from?

...because:

1. `Type.GetType` takes a .NET type name, not a COM ProgId.
2. Windows Installer (at least on Windows 2003) doesn't have a ProgId.

In summary: Use P/Invoke (`DllImport`, etc.) to talk to the MSI API.

Comment: Great, I do not know exactly what P/Invoke is; I did not manage to find a runable code on the web, it seems to be a well respected secret. So it could be a solution but currently I more or less end up with some DllImport. Please regard me as a newbie in this matter.