# Get Product Version using upgrade code for a product installed

Tags: c#, windows, winapi

I am trying to retrieve the product version of an installed msi using upgrade code.
I tried using MsiGetProductInfo api but it doesn't return me the result.

I couldn't find the application under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\MSFT\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall.

But Instead I did find my application some place else in registry under Installer\Products.

I know that similar question has bben asked here:
  [Get Product Code of installed Msi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6345262/get-product-code-of-installed-msi)

but does someone has a better way of doing it.

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7374646/reading-current-installed-version-of-an-application-using-windows-api

Comment: This is how I solved.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7374646/reading-current-installed-version-of-an-application-using-windows-api

Answer (score 1):

I had pretty much the same issue just now.  If you have the upgrade-code GUID, you can do this:

```
WindowsInstaller.Installer installer =
   Activator.CreateInstance(/* left as an exercise for the reader */);
foreach (string productCode in installer.get_RelatedProducts("your-upgradecode-guid")) {
   string productVersion = installer.get_ProductInfo(productCode, "VersionString");
}
```

Trouble is, there could be multiple related products, so how you handle that is up to you.

EDIT:  If you install per-user by default or by mistake, then you might not get the product code with RelatedProducts if you run the query as a different user than the MSI was installed for... even if the installation was more or less public.

Comment: Hi Greg, I did solve the problem. I used MsiEnumeratedproducts which did solve my problem.