# Reading current installed version of an application using windows api

Tags: c#, windows, winapi

I was trying to use windows api to find out the version info of an installed application.

I used the upgrade code to find out the product code using MsiEnumRelatedProducts api, but when I try to use MsiGetProductInfo using the product code, the version info comes back as garbage.

Here is my MsiGetProductInfo api:

```
[DllImport("msi.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
private static extern Int32 MsiGetProductInfo(
    string product, string property, [Out] StringBuilder valueBuf,
    ref Int32 len);

MsiGetProductInfo(sbProductCode, "INSTALLPROPERTY_INSTALLVERSION", builder, ref len);
```

Any thoughts on what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I got it resolved by myself: I had to just change the string property to use VersionString and that did the trick.

Comment: you should post your code as an answer.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out TMB, I will keep it mind for next time onwards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what I did that my solved my problem.

```
        Int32 m_len = 11512;
        StringBuilder m_versionInfo = new StringBuilder(m_len);

        StringBuilder m_sbProductCode = GetProductCodeFromMsiUpgradeCode();
        MsiGetProductInfo(m_sbProductCode.ToString(), "**VersionString**", m_versionInfo, ref m_len);

        return m_versionInfo.ToString();
```

This did return me the version string ,and also converted from decimal into string format like 1.4.3.

Comment: where did you find the appropriate string to use? i tried 'INSTALLPROPERTY_VERSIONSTRING', 'ProductVersion', 'INSTALLPROPERTY_VERSION' and every other representation i was able to find of it through out MSDN, 'VersionString' was not to be found anywhere... Did you find a list of the actual values somewhere? TIA

Comment: This worked but I don't know why you used **VersionString**. I did it without the asterixis and it worked

Answer (score 3):

In response to @JoshHetland the string to pass is the CamelCase postfix of the `INSTALLPROPERTY_VERSIONSTRING` - remember that MSI is case sensitive.

So:

`INSTALLPROPERTY_VERSIONSTRING` becomes `VersionString`

`INSTALLPROPERTY_INSTALLDATE` becomes `InstallDate`

and so on.

Complete list of properties available is on the [MSDN page for the MsiGetProductInfo function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370130.aspx) .

Comment: Thank you so much for pointing out the note which should have been documented in InstallShield or MSDN.

Answer (score 0):

Application.ProductVersion works for me, no need to call WinAPI manually (I am still in .Net 1.1 though)

Comment: @Erick: I just updated my question.I guess this will do for current application.

Comment: In general, you can use FileVersionInfo from System.Diagnostics: FileVersionInfo oFileVersionInfo = FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo(sSomeFileName); string sVersion = oFileVersionInfo.FileVersion;

Comment: @Erick: In my opinion using fileversion is not a safe idea because you are assuming that the file would be installed in that location. Using the windows api would be a better option.