# How to show Product version in windows form application published by installshield

Tags: c#, winforms, version, installshield, setup-project

I want to show current version of my windows form application project in a window. while i publish my project using visual studio publish wizard below code meet my requirement.

```
    public string CurrentVersion
    {
        get
        {
            return ApplicationDeployment.IsNetworkDeployed
                   ? ApplicationDeployment.CurrentDeployment.CurrentVersion.Revision.ToString()
                   : Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Version.Revision.ToString();
        }
    }
```

Now I want to publish my project using Installshield and creating msi project. 
How can I get product version when using this approach?

Comment: where do you want to put the version? In a Label in your form?

Comment: I already add the possible answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this:

```
var yrversion = Application.ProductVersion;
this.label1.Text = String.Format("HRIS Version {0}", yrversion);
```

I already researched and put these code many times on any of my projects.

Edit:

This is where the application version comes from.
[image: Here]

And you will see the changes

[image: Like this one]

Don't forget to publish it.

Comment: this code returns: 1.0.0.0 while this is not the current version

Comment: check your visual studio application properties. and you should see why this return as 1.0.0.0

Comment: Do you publish your project using a seprate installshield project?

Comment: I don't. But, I know the best way to do this first is to publish it there to register the "Version itself" by publishing it first and then make an installer on InstallShield Wizard. Even on the other StackOverflow questions and answer does this hardcoded.

Answer (score 0):

To get the version of an MSI file you need to know its ProductCode (from the Properties window of your setup project where I assume you set it).

The core API is the Win32 MsiGetProductInfo(), but a search reveals that this SO post is a C# example:

[Reading current installed version of an application using windows api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7374646/reading-current-installed-version-of-an-application-using-windows-api)