# How to check installed msi details from registry using msbuild

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, msbuild-4.0

I want to check an installed msi product details like product key, code and others using msbuild target.

I want to uninstall the msi using the product code using the following syntax:

msiexec /x {PRODUCT-CODE-GUID-HERE}

Can anyone help me with sample code.

Thanks & Regards,
Santosh Kumar Patro

Comment: Will the productcode of the msi remain fixed through out the life cycle of the product? If yes can I use the constant productcode in the msbuild script.Please advise me in the above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After my analysis I found that there are two  approaches available to resolve the issue as mentioned below:

a. Read the product code from Registry using C# and hook it up with a custom task and invoke it in Custom Build proj file.

In order to accomplish the above mentioned point the following links are useful:
[Get Product Code of installed Msi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6345262/get-product-code-of-installed-msi)
http://tech.pro/tutorial/934/creating-msbuild-tasks-in-csharp

b. Uninstall the installed MSI using Powershell script. Here I need to invoke the powershell script from the Custom Build proj file.

In order to accomplish the above mentioned point the following links are useful:
http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/deployment/advanced-enterprise-web-deployment/running-windows-powershell-scripts-from-msbuild-project-files
http://nzbart.blogspot.in/2012/11/correctly-executing-powershell-script.html
http://thoughtsofmarcus.blogspot.in/2012/12/clever-uninstall-of-msi.html

Thanks & Regards,
Santosh Kumar Patro